# Android Productflavors build all

Tags: android, gradle

I would like to have multiple android builds, but it isn't building the way I would like.

I am using Android Studio to make my app and build it with the following `productFlavors` in the gradle file:

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        armv7 {
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I have Android Studio build the application, it only builds the `x86` version. If I remove the `x86` from the flavors, it builds `armeabi-v7a`. How can I get it to build both versions?

Comment: `gradle assemble` will build all flavors

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do this to get both:

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        armv7 {
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }
        x86 {
            ndk {
                abiFilters "x86"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing this, it builds the first one, but then it doesn't work on my emulator

Comment: to get the proper build on your emulator, use the "Build Variants" options (far left border, in the middle should have this button). From there, you can select the build variant that will load to your emulator.